# Operate on a list of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of columns from a dataframe

```
df_date=[df[var1],df[var2]]
```

I want to change the data in that columns to date time type

```
for t in df_date:
    pd.DatetimeIndex(t)
```

for some reason its not working
I whould like to understand what is more general solution for applying sevral  operations on several columns.

Comment: Please include some data such it is clear what you want to do. To me, it looks that you are looping over a list of Series objects (i.e. one column from a DataFrame), so t is the Series is self, not an index. You can clarify your question by adding data

Comment: The items in the list are columns from a dataframe, i want to change each column to a date object

Comment: The reason why it does work is that you don't overwrite your columns with the new datetime index. The results of the funtion can be imposed as t=pd.DatetimeIndex(t)

Comment: it didnt work, ive tried to overwrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, you can do:

```
for column_name in ["var1", "var2"]:
    df[column_name] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df[column_name])
```

Comment: I'm looking for more general solution for applying sevral operations on several columns.

Comment: The statement above is identical to the one in your question, I think you should try to explain clearer in your example what you want to achieve and what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to convert a dataframe's entire content to datetime. You can also filter out the columns you need and apply it only to them.

```
df[['column1', 'column2']] = df[['column1', 'column2']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

---

Note that a list of series and a DataFrame are **not** the same thing.

A DataFrame is accessed like this:

```
df[[columns]]
```

While a list of series is looks like this:

```
[seriesA, seriesB]
```